# Composite key in Hibernate Annotations confusion

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I have two tables say 'A' and 'B'. A third table 'C' has two columns that directly refer to 'A' and 'B' i.e. 'C' contains 'A_id' and 'B_id' that refer to A's id and B's id respectively. There is unique key defined on 'A_id' and 'B_id'. But there is no id column in 'C'. How can I go about defining the model class for 'C' without altering the schema for 'C'. I am very new to using Hibernate annotations so please help me out. 'A' and 'B' have other columns as well and have their model classes already defined.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like C is just a *join table*. There is no need to map C explicitly. You can map relation from A to B or vice versa using **@JoinTable** annotation. Please take a look at the example at [One To Many Join Table Setup](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/OneToManyJoinTableSetup.htm). There is no mapping for EMP_PHONE, it is just a *join table* between phone and employee.